# combine tabs and grid layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently learning, please bear with me. I try to make a holy grail layout using grid while making tabs to change middle content (and maybe left one in the future).

I used this suggestion I found here to make the tabs : https://jsfiddle.net/a2fh8n4e/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var previousActiveTabIndex = 0;

    $(".tab-switcher").on('click', function (event) {
        if (event.type === "click") {
            var tabClicked = $(this).data("tab-index");
            if(tabClicked != previousActiveTabIndex) {
                $("#allTabsContainer .tab-container").each(function () {
                    if($(this).data("tab-index") == tabClicked) {
                        $(".tab-container").hide();
                        $(this).show();
                        previousActiveTabIndex = $(this).data("tab-index");
                        return;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "alegreya", serif;
}

body {
  min-width: 550px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% auto 15%;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "left middle right" "footer footer footer";
}

#header {
  border-width: 2px, 2px, 0, 2px;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#left {
  border-width: 4px, 1px, 0px, 2px;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-style: solid;
}

#middle {
  border-width: 0, 1px, 2px, 1px;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-style: solid;
}

#right {
  border-width: 0, 2px, 2px, 1px;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-style: solid;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

#footer {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
  
.tab-switcher {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HEADER AND TABS -->
<div style="grid-area: header" id="header">
  <ul>
    <li class="tab-switcher" data-tab-index="0" tabindex="0">Collecte</li>
    <li class="tab-switcher" data-tab-index="1" tabindex="0">Journal</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- CONTENT ZONE -->
<div id="allTabsContainer">
  <div class="tab-container" data-tab-index="0">
    <!-- TAB1 -->
    <div style="grid-area: left" id="left">
      <p>Wood : <span id="Wood"></span></p>
    </div>
    <div style="grid-area: middle" id="middle">
      <button class="Collect" id="But_wood">Pick wood</button>
      <button class="Collect" id="But_tree">Cut a tree</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-container" data-tab-index="1" style="display:none;">
    <!-- TAB2 -->
    <div style="grid-area: left" id="left">
      <p>Stone : <span id="Stone"></span></p>
      <p>Grass : <span id="Grass"></span></p>
    </div>
    <div style="grid-area: middle" id="middle">
      <button class="Collect" id="But_stone">Collect stone</button>
      <button class="Collect" id="But_grass">Collect grass</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--div class="tab-container" data-tab-index="2" style="display:none;">
        Some content for Tab - 3
      </div-->
</div>

<!-- LOGS & CHAT SHOULD BE ALWAYS ACTIVE -->
<div style="grid-area: right" id="right">
  <p>Logs</p>
  <p id="log">...</p>
</div>

<!-- FOOTER SHOULD BE ALWAYS ACTIVE -->
<div style="grid-area: footer" id="footer">
  <p>contenu relatif au site et à l'auteur</p>
</div>

<!-- MISC. & SCRIPTS -->
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
```

- I tried to combine the two but can't reach something where it works as intended with the correct layout. I can not combine `style="grid-area: xxx` within the selected tabs https://jsfiddle.net/j6cemskg/35/
  => I want the buttons to be in the middle column, while having ressources amount on a left panel, and both should change according to tab chosen.
- Also, if anyone can give insight on how to avoid the trouble to have multiple ID like "left0","left1", etc. for each and every tab (maybe class attribute ? Can I have multiple classes assigned to a same element ?)

I would gladly take any advice concerning those troubles, thank you.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask], then revise to add your script. Put it all in a demo using the editor. It's difficult to help without seeing the complete picture. Also take the [tour].

Comment: "layout with javascript" please show JavaScript you have attempted, outline what it is supposed to accomplish and where if fails so we may assist you in the one challenge you have with it.  What is "works as intended with the correct layout" your intended result?

Comment: I tried to make a snipset, it was indeed unclear before, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is as follows, but I've changed quite a bit of your code to simplify things.

Basically, I've adjusted your HTML so that the grid display is based on the `#allTabsContainer` element, and made all elements that make up areas of that grid siblings in order that they can be placed in the grid defined on the `#allTabsContainer` element.

I've also removed the jQuery entirely, and revised the approach used to toggle the display of the various grid-elements.

Explanatory comments for changes, and functionality, are in the code below:

```js
// defining a named function using Arrow syntax, to which a reference to the
// Event Object is passed (automatically) from EventTarget.addEventListener():
const   updateToggle = (evt) => {
        // we retrieve the element that has triggered the function-call to
        // which the function was bound:
        let switched = evt.currentTarget,
            // from that element we use the HTMLElement.dataset API to
            // retrieve the value of the named attribute; we use camelCase
            // to access attributes that include hyphens; so 'data-tab-index'
            // is accessed as below:
                toShow = switched.dataset.tabIndex,
            // from the switched element we navigate to the closest ancestor
            // that contains a 'data-tab-show' attribute:
            toggleDispatch = switched.closest('[data-tab-show]');
            
        // with that Element we - again - utilise the HTMLElement.dataset
        // API to set the the 'data-to-show' attribute-value to the value
        // we retrieved from the clicked ('switched') element:
        toggleDispatch.dataset.tabShow = toShow;
      },
      // here we retrieve the elements that will serve as switches, the
      // li.tab-switcher elements:
            toggles = document.querySelectorAll('li.tab-switcher');
      
// we use NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the NodeList:
toggles.forEach(
  // here we use an Arrow function to bind the updateToggle() function
  // (note the deliberately omitted parentheses) as the event-handler
  // for the 'click' event on the elements of the NodeList:
    (el) => el.addEventListener('click', updateToggle)
);
```

```css
/* simple reset to ensure that all elements are using the same
   box-sizing algorithm, font, list-style-type, margin and padding */
*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: normal normal 1rem / 1.5 sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#allTabsContainer {
  display: grid;
  /* setting a 0.5em gap between adjacent elements,
     whether vertically, or horizontally, adjacent: */
  gap: 0.5em;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header"
    "left middle right"
    "footer footer footer";
  /* there are differences between 'auto' and '1fr'
     but they're minor, and your intent seems to be
     to use the entirety of the space available, so
     I chose to replace 'auto' with '1fr': */
  grid-template-columns: 15% 1fr 15%;
  /* using grid-template-rows to specify the heights
     of the various rows: */
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr 50px;
  /* setting a margin on the block-axis of the element
     to 0 (this is implicit from the 'reset' above; but
     if it needs to be changed I like it to be explicitly
     stated for ease of changing) the 'block-axis' is
     top-to-bottom in English and left-to-right languages: */
  margin-block: 0;
  /* I put a margin of 20px on the inline-axis (the axis of
     writing-flow, left-to-right in English): */
  margin-inline: 20px;
  /* this makes the minimum height of the element 100 viewport-units
     tall, but allows it to expand if the content demands it: */
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#allTabsContainer > div {
  /* placing a border on all elements taking part in the grid: */
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

#header {
  /* positioning the grid-element in the named grid-area: */
  grid-area: header;
}

#header ul {
  /* using flex-layout to arrange the elements to flow in the
     inline axis: */
  display: flex;
  /* placing a 1em gap between adjacent elements: */
  gap: 1em;
  /* vertically aligning the child elements: */
  align-content: center;
  /* aligning the child elements to the start of the inline-flow
     (to the left in a left-to-right language such as English): */
  justify-content: start;
}

.tab-switcher {
  cursor: pointer;
  /* setting the defaults for the text-decoration
     (not using 'text-decoration' shorthand): */
  text-decoration-color: transparent;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-thickness: 0.1em;
  /* transitioning all properties: */
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

/* selects all .tab-switcher elements when they match
   any of the supplied pseudo-classes listed in the :is()
   pseudo-class: */
.tab-switcher:is(:hover, :active, :focus) {
  color: rebeccapurple;
  text-decoration-color: currentColor;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-thickness: 0.2em;
}

/* positioning elements in the named grid-areas: */
.tab-container.left {
  grid-area: left;
}
.tab-container.middle {
  grid-area: middle;
}

#right {
  grid-area: right;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #ccc;
  grid-area: footer;
  padding-inline: 1em;
  /* again using CSS logical properties, here we align the text
     to the end of the inline-axis (the right, in a left-to-right
     language such as English): */
  text-align: end;
}

/* here we select all element(s) which are not a '.tab-switcher'
   element which have a data-tab-index attribute and are a
   descendant of an element(s) with a data-tab-show attribute: */
[data-tab-show] [data-tab-index]:not(.tab-switcher) {
  /* we visually hide those elements (this may be imperfect for
     use in non-visual media, such as screen-readers; please check): */
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* here we undo the hiding of those elements, by selecting elements which
   are not '.tab-switcher' elements, that have a data-tab-index
   attribute-value equal to 0 (or 1) which is a descendant of an element(s)
   that have a data-tab-show attribute-value of 0 (or 1): */
[data-tab-show="0"] [data-tab-index="0"]:not(.tab-switcher),
[data-tab-show="1"] [data-tab-index="1"]:not(.tab-switcher) {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

button {
  /* adding padding to the <button> elements, purely for aesthetic purposes: */
  padding-block: 0.2em;
  padding-inline: 0.4em;
}
```

```html
<!-- the grid display is now specified on the following element, and all elements taking part
     in the grid are now siblings; this is so that they're all 'aware' of the grid in their
     parent element and can be positioned in those areas.
     You'll note that there is a new data-* attribute, the "data-tab-show" attribute with a
     value set to 0 on page-load (this is modified in the JavaScript that handles the
     toggling: -->
<div id="allTabsContainer" data-tab-show="0">
  <!-- HEADER AND TABS -->
  <div id="header">
    <ul>
      <li class="tab-switcher" data-tab-index="0" tabindex="0">Collecte</li>
      <li class="tab-switcher" data-tab-index="1" tabindex="0">Journal</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- CONTENT ZONE -->
  <!-- I've also removed the id for the #middle0, #middle1, #left0, #left1...
       elements, since it did nothing particularly useful and made it more
       awkward to position those elements; instead I added a class to make
       it easier ('middle' and 'left') to allow for positioning within
       the grid: -->
  <div class="tab-container middle" data-tab-index="0">
    <!-- TAB1 -->
    <button class="Collect" id="But_wood">Pick wood</button>
    <button class="Collect" id="But_tree">Cut a tree</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-container middle" data-tab-index="1">
    <!-- TAB2 -->
    <button class="Collect" id="But_stone">Collect stone</button>
    <button class="Collect" id="But_grass">Collect grass</button>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-container left" data-tab-index="0">
    <p>Wood : <span id="Wood"></span></p>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-container left" data-tab-index="1">
    <p>Stone : <span id="Stone"></span></p>
    <p>Grass : <span id="Grass"></span></p>
  </div>

  <!-- LOGS & CHAT SHOULD BE ALWAYS ACTIVE -->
  <div id="right">
    <p>Logs</p>
    <p id="log">...</p>
  </div>

  <!-- FOOTER SHOULD BE ALWAYS ACTIVE -->
  <div style="grid-area: footer" id="footer">
    <p>contenu relatif au site et à l'auteur</p>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- MISC. & SCRIPTS -->
<!-- commented out as it causes a GET error in the console on sites
     where this script doesn't exist (and while I'm looking at the
     console for errors it's distracting to have an expected error
     there:
  <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
  -->
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p2mLe4vx/1/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`align-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content).
  - [Attribute-selectors `[attr]`, `[attr="value"]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).
  - [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
  - [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display/).
  - [`font`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font).
  - [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap/).
  - [`grid-area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area).
  - [`grid-template-areas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas).
  - [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
  - [`grid-template-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows).
  - [`:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is).
  - [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
  - [Logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties).
  - [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).
  - [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`HTMLElement.dataset` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
  - [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Comment: It changed a little bit of code indeed, a bit too much for me to be confortable with, to be frank.
Still, a lot of useful information and things I will definitely pick up on to improve my code, thank you.

Comment: While the JavaScript might be too much of a change (though I’d argue it’s a lot easier to follow than your current jQuery), the HTML pretty much has to be that way, since the children of a grid are the only elements that are aware the named grid-areas. The CSS, and JavaScript, are of course entirely changeable. May I ask where your “discomfort” comes in?

Answer (score 0):

Here I will concentrate on the layout using the grid with 4 areas.

I will then show how to handle clicks of the tabs and some actions related to that using a "target" data attribute.
I will leave the style of color etc. to you but put borders on to illustrate each area.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".tab-switcher").on('click', function(event) {
    let tabClicked = $(this).data("tabTarget");
    let lastTab = $(this).closest(".tab-switcher-list").data("last-clicked");
    $("#allTabsContainer .tab-container").hide().filter(tabClicked).show();
  }).first().trigger('click');
});
```

```css
html {
  /* background-color: #aaaaaa; out just because I dislike gray for visually challenged people reasons */
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "alegreya", serif;
}

body {
  /* min-width: 550px; */
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  border: solid 1px lime;
}

.page-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto 1fr auto / auto 1fr auto;
}

.container-header {
  padding: 1rem;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}

.container-left {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.container-main {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.container-right {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
}

.container-footer {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}

.container-header {
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.page-pane {
  /* base style for all panes */
  border-color: #CCCCCC;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 0.125em;
  border-left-width: 0.125em;
  border-bottom-width: 0.125em;
  border-right-width: 0.125em
}

.container-left {
  border-right-width: 0.0625em;
  border-color: cyan;
}

.container-main {
  min-height: 20rem;
}

.container-right {
  border-right-width: 0.0625em;
  border-color: magenta;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.container-footer {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  text-align: right;
  align-self: end;
}

.tab-switcher-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: solid orange 0.0875em;
  height: 2.5rem;
}

nav .tab-switcher-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 0.25em solid #444444;
  height: 1.25em;
}

.tab-switcher {
  flex: auto;
  margin: 0.25em;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #44ddCC;
  height: 1.25rem;
  padding-left: 0.25em;
  padding-right: 0.25em;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="page-container">
  <div class="container-header page-pane">
    <div>I am the header pane</div>
    <nav class="tab-switcher-container">
      <ul class=tab-switcher-list>
        <li class="tab-switcher" data-tab-target=".tab-1">Collecte</li>
        <li class="tab-switcher" data-tab-target=".tab-2">Journal</li>
        <li class="tab-switcher" data-tab-target=".tab-cheese">Cheese</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="container-left page-pane">
    <div>I am the left pane</div>
    <div id="allTabsContainer">
      <div class="tab-container tab-1" data-tab-index="0">
        <div>
          <p>Wood:<span>I am wood, get wood</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-container tab-2" data-tab-index="1">
        <div>
          <p>Stone:<span>I am stone, get stone</span></p>
          <p>Grass:<span>Grass I am - why am in in stone?!</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-container tab-cheese" data-tab-index="1">
        <div>
          <p>Cheese:<span>I am cheese!</span></p>
          <p>Flavor:<span>Cheddrer Cheese!</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-main page-pane">
    <div>I am the main pane</div>
    <button class="Collect get-wood">Pick wood</button>
    <button class="Collect cut-tree">Cut a tree</button>
    <button class="Collect get-stone">Collect stone</button>
    <button class="Collect get-grass">Collect grass</button>
    <p>Here I am make me happy</p>
    <p>Here I am make me happy</p>
    <p>Here I am make me happy</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container-right logs-container page-pane">
    <div>I am the right page pane</div>
    <p>Logs</p>
    <p id="log">...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container-footer page-pane">
    <div>I am the footer pane</div>
    <div>
      <p>contenu relatif au site et à l'auteur</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```